# Using OWASP ZAP Proxy for existing suite of Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, owasp, zap

We have a suite of automated regression tests driven using Selenium for an Angular app with a .NET Core WEB API backend.

The intention is to include some automated security testing as part of our overnight build/test run.

From reading so far it looks like running ZAP as an intercepting proxy between Selenium and our web application is the way to go (see 'Proxy Regression/Unit Tests' in https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#exploring-the-app) but I'm struggling to find clear documentation/examples.

What is the simplest way to achieve this using OWASP ZAP, and are there any definitive articles/examples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the packaged full scan: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/

Set the port and then proxy your selenium tests through ZAP. Use the `-D` parameter to pause ZAP until your tests have finished. For more ZAP automation options see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Comment: So pull down the latest docker image, run the zap-full-scan.py script with the -P and -D arguments to set up the port and the amount of time expected for the E2E tests, then run the Selenium tests with the proxy configured?

Comment: Essentially yes, but you'll need to do some messing around with docker networking in order to be able to proxy your tests through ZAP.

Comment: Unfortunately our Bamboo server is running on Windows Server 2012 which doesn't support Docker. In the absence of docker would using the API via the .NET Nuget package be a reasonable way to go?

Comment: In that case you'll need to install ZAP, start it in daemon mode and then control it via the API. FYI we're working on an automation framework which should make things much easier for cases like this, but thats not quite ready yet...

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate all the great work on ZAP.